# Syntax error on else: statement in code + idk why it keeps saying I have a bad title

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, my problem is I need to put mondayAssign right where I have it cause it appears it will just ask the question everywhere else and I don't want it too so I have to do this and I have an error on elif: any one wanna help?

```
__import__("replit").clear()

whatReturn = "monday"
f = open('hold.txt',  'r')
g = f.seek(0)
h = f.readlines()
for line in h:
  pass

def monday():
 if whatReturn in line:
   mondayAssign = input("Assign a task for monday: ")
 else:
   print("error has occured.")
monday()
def mondayy():
 if whatReturn in line:
   mondayAdd = input("Anything else you would like to add, 'yes' or 'no': ")
   mondayAdd == 'yes'
   mondayDoubleAssign = input("Assign a task for monday: ")
 elif:
   print("Error!!!")
 else:
   mondayAssign = input("Assign a task for monday: ")
#the last else is just a place to store the mondayAssign cause it appears I cant put it anywhere else without it just printing itself and I don't want to ask same question twice
mondayy()       
print(mondayAssign, mondayDoubleAssign)
```

Comment: you have an `elif:` with no condition. `elif` must have a condition to check.

Comment: I'm assuming I can do else: instead which I did try but then the next else: just has a error like a poison.

Comment: You're getting the second error because you now have two `else` statements for one `if`

Comment: Have a good day too man.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, you use the unconditional `elif` construct. Either add some condition or replace `elif` with `else`. In the event that you want to handle the exception, you need to use the `try except` construction.
Here is a variant using "else":

```
__import__("replit").clear()

whatReturn = "monday"
f = open('hold.txt',  'r')
g = f.seek(0)
h = f.readlines()
for line in h:
  pass # This is extra code

def monday(h):
    for line in h:
        if whatReturn in line:
            mondayAssign = input("Assign a task for monday: ") # to use "line" you must first define it
        else:
            print("error has occured.")
monday(h)
def mondayy(h):
    for line in h:
        if whatReturn in line:
            mondayAdd = input("Anything else you would like to add, 'yes' or 'no': ")
            mondayAdd == 'yes' #it's not very clear why there is a comparison
            mondayDoubleAssign = input("Assign a task for monday: ")
        elif some_condition:
            print("Error!!!")
        else:
            mondayAssign = input("Assign a task for monday: ")
#the last else is just a place to store the mondayAssign cause it appears I             cant put it anywhere else without it just printing itself and I don't want to ask same question twice
mondayy(h)       
print(mondayAssign, mondayDoubleAssign)
```

If you look at the code in general, I think you should get a better understanding of loops and conditional statements, since you seem to have problems with them. Do not grab onto everything at once :) It is better to first study each of the topics in detail, and then try to combine them. This also applies to functions, by the way. Here's a little scribbled on using it all:

```
#lets begin from loops
#simple usage:
for some_variable in some_sequence:
    print(some_variable) # some variable access only in loop it means that you can use it only in loop body(4 spaces)
#now briefly about conditional operators:
if some_statement:
    print("something")
elif some_other_statement:
    print("do something else") # it means optional condition
else:
    print("do something different in any way that does not fit the above")
#again, you need to remember about the scope, that is, something will work inside the condition only if it is written after 4 spaces
#now briefly about functions:
#a function is an algorithm that we have named by some name and, as a rule, we use repeatedly. In parentheses, we pass the arguments to the function, that is, external data that needs to be used inside the algorithm.
def simple_func(arg_one, arg_two):
    print(arg_one, arg_two)
simple_variable_one = "hello"
simple_variable_two = "world!"
simple_func(simple_variable_one, simple_variable_two) #output: hello world
```

Good luck learning Python, I hope you succeed!